# UINavigationViewController control UIContainerView embed segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have the following scenario:
[image: Main.storyboard]

A UIViewController is embedded inside a UINavigationViewController. The UIViewController has a UINavigationItem attached to it and has a UIContainerView as a subview. The UIContainerView has a embed segue to a UITableViewController with some static rows.

> How can I make it so that when the user presses the Advanced row's
>   little arrow image on the right, the UIViewContainer's embed segue get
>   changed to reference another UITableViewController and have a Back
>   button on the UINavigationController so that the user can navigate
>   back to the original UITableViewController(with animations)?

Basically I want the user to be able to switch between Settings and Advanced Settings.

**Things I have tried**:
I tried having the container view have an embed segue to an UINavigationController. The first UITableViewController was set up to have a root-view controller segue relationship with the UINavigationController. I then made a show segue between the arrow (button) and another UITableViewController. This way I was able to transition between settings -> advanced settings -> settings, but I had double navigation bars. One is the bar I want, the white one on top, and the other is a gray one that appears below and where the back button is displayed. I want it to be a single navigation bar (the white one).

[image: Settings Screen][image: Advanced Settings Screen]

> I have no problem using code to achieve what I want (Objective-C or Swift).

Comment: I forgot to mention this, I will edit the question after this, but I have no problem using code. in fact I was thinking of using prepareSegue to keep a reference to the first UINavigationController and then when the UITableView appears programmatically add the back button to the UINavigationView.

Comment: If I understand your goal correctly, you have multiple options. 1) use non-static table, and reload changing the rows displayed based on Basic/Adv settings, or 2) use a new NavigationController as the Container content, with its NavBar hidden (just push/pop from code), or 3) use separate views / table views as the Container content, and use simple view animations to transition between the different Settings tables. Do you have a "this is how I want it to look / function" idea already?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did it by code by adding the back button and dismissing the "Advanced Settings" view controller programmatically. I achieved this by created a show segue to the "Advanced Settings" UITableView. I then subclassed the UITableViewController:

```
@implementation AdvancedSettingsController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UIBarButtonItem* backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(goBack)];
  self.navigationController = (UINavigationController*)self.parentViewController;
  self.parentViewController.parentViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0;
}

-(IBAction)goBack
{
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

I just wanted to have it be done using the Xcode builder to automate the process a bit, because I do not like the self.parentViewController.parentViewController thing, because if I change my controllers this will stop working and is a little hard to read.

[End result (webm) - https://webmshare.com/m8Kne](https://webmshare.com/m8Kne)